# AWS Elastic Beanstalk: access System variables

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat7, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've a traditional Tomcat web app, that connects to a Postgres DB with JNDI (reading the context.xml).
In AWS EBS there is the possibility to use system properties to read specific things like jdbc connection parameters, and that would be great to easily use the same package for different environments (dev, staging, production) without going to change the context.xml file.
Since I'm using JNDI DataSource, I'm accessing the original datasource, and then changing the url and password, in this way:

```
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource ds = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/myapp");
    String jdbcURL = System.getProperty("JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING"); 
    String username = System.getProperty("PARAM1"); 
    String password = System.getProperty("PARAM2"); 
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(jdbcURL)){
        ds.setUrl(jdbcURL);
        ds.setUsername(username);
        ds.setPassword(password);
    }
```

Using Tomcat DataSource I have access to setters and getters of the connection parameters.
Tested it locally (adding the System parameters in the VM arguments of Tomcat, it works perfectly.
But when I upload to my test environment in AWS EBS, these parameters are empty at the beginning (when the application is loaded), but they are available later on: tested them in a jsp page in this way

```
The JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING environment property is:
<%= System.getProperty("JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING") %>
</p>

<p>
The PARAM1 environment property is:
<%= System.getProperty("PARAM1") %>
</p>
<p>]
The PARAM2 environment property is:
<%= System.getProperty("PARAM2") %>
</p>
```

and they correct values are printed.
The only guess I can have is that the System properties are loaded later on, while I set up the connection to the database in the Listener called on application startup (set up in web.xml).

Any idea why it fails so?

Thanks,

Rohi

EDIT: I've found the problem, but not the solution:
The problem is that when the DataSource is loaded with in the lookup() method, it also tried to establish a connection! It will not succeed cause in context.xml the url is localhost, and I don't have a DB there when I deploy.

Anybody knows how NOT to connect immediately, but wait till the first getConnection() call?
this is my context.xml

```
<Resource auth="Container" 
        driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" 
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" 
        maxActive="1000" maxIdle="1000" maxWait="2000"
        autoReconnect="true" 
        logAbandoned="true" 
        name="jdbc/townflix" 
        type="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"  
        url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb?prepareThreshold=3" 
        username="user" 
        password="pass"
```

/>

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it fails, but i can tell you the way i do it in my personal project.

I generate and overwrite the context.xml with my configuration using a .ebextensions/*.config file, thus setting my DataSource correctly before the container starts.

See: https://github.com/Craftware/Kornell/blob/master/kornell-api/src/main/webapp/.ebextensions/tomcat7.config

Comment: Thanks, but I have 2 different environment in EBS, the production and the test that is exactly the same apart from the JDBC string.... so I would still need to change manually when I move between environments.

Comment: I have 2 envs too. If you check the script, you'll see that i download and run a script, that replaces the environment variables and outputs the result to context.xml.

Comment: great! Sorry I didn't notice. I'll use that while I try to figure out what happens in the scenario above. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, i'm trying to find out a better way to do this too, will post here if i do.